# What can I do about 100-year-old stairs that are pulling away from wall

Tags: stairs

100-year-old stairs pulling away from wall.  And there is a little give.

Comment: This link explains [How to add images](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the installer, builder or manufacturer for any warranty type of repair...I'm kidding. Your best bet is to get a Carpenter or Stair Builder that uses glues, screws & bolts behind or even upon the finished surfaces...finish screws are wonderful.

Nails, spikes & staples are the norm & they can't & won't last, they're held by friction alone. Glue Coated nails are only good for a decade at the most, glue only lasts if its hold can't flex or break loose. A stair is a moving part, if given the chance, & will only continue to loosen until another object retains it.

Comment: Thx so much.  I have to clear the bottom of the stairwell. ( plaster lathe- ugh) just to get a look--- one stair builder ( who didn't even look at the bottom exposed) was like I yea we will probsbly have to build a whole new staircase

Comment: Says I don't have edit privileges thus can't post pictures.  If you have email I could shoot 2 poctures

Comment: They are 100 year old stairs. Not year old

Comment: Nope, I don't need pictures & you don't need that stair builder. The side of the stair should just be baseboard & shouldn't have anything to do with stair attachment. But, you might have broken plaster holding the baseboard out. The underside of the stair is where lag bolts would go in, under the treads & not in the bottom on the stair stringer. Loose handrails might be fixed on the underside of them with a wrench, if there's a hole or plug at each end. This hole, but typically plug, would also apply to the newel posts. But, you may have none of those & it'll have to be a screw job.

Comment: Thx iggy. I'm still going to have to expose the bottom by removing the plaster and wire etc.  The stairs are just attached on one side. If you are walking up the stairs ( there are 19 with curvature at the last 4) and look a few stairs 1/2 way up say stairs 7-11 look like they are kinda of sliding left yo right out of the groove that is attached to wall

Comment: Oh, well do what you have to do. You'll be an expert plasterer by the end, if that's any plus to permanently fixing the problem. It'll have to be an exploration. Try using a grinder or circular saw just above the trim, if it's a straight line baseboard type top end. A circular nibbling will leave the rest of the wall undisturbed & then you can do drywall behind the trim or baseboard with just a tiny seam to tape (mesh) & mud-in.

Comment: Thx lol.  I really think it has to do with the stringer either moving or getting loose because it's only the middle stairs.  If I hear you what I am shooting for is stabilization. Which would be good AND inexpensive

Comment: Yep, I'd suspect it's just the top section & lag bolts through the stringer will solidify the entire stair. You may find that it also dropped a little, a 2x4 wedged in from beneath should fix additional little issues as well.